# Issue rendering correct visual for Albers US Choropleth Map with d3.js and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, topojson

I am trying to figure out what went wrong with my code since I have not been able to generate anything else than a big square of a single color while I try to get a colorScale for each element with the class "county" of this Albers US map.

The project should look like this: https://choropleth-map.freecodecamp.rocks/

The weirdest thing is that I validate the test.

I am using d3.js and put it in a React 18 component and I use Babel for rendering through another HTML file.

The snippet which might be blocking:

```
  const createChoroplethMap = (counties, educationData, width, height, margins) => {
    // create SVG element
    const svg = d3.select("#chomap")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margins.left + margins.right)
      .attr("height", height + margins.top + margins.bottom);
  
    // create projection and path generator
    const projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa();
    const pathGenerator = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
  
    // create color scale
    const colorScale = d3.scaleQuantize()
      .domain([0, d3.max(educationData, d => d.bachelorsOrHigher)])
      .range(d3.schemeBlues[9]);
  
    // draw counties
    svg.selectAll(".county")
      .data(topojson.feature(counties, counties.objects.counties).features)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "county")
      .attr("d", pathGenerator)
      .attr("fill", d => {
        const county = educationData.find(e => e.fips === d.id);
        console.log(county.bachelorsOrHigher)
        return colorScale(county.bachelorsOrHigher);
      })
      .attr("data-fips", d => d.id)
      .attr("data-education", d => {
        const county = educationData.find(e => e.fips === d.id);
        return county.bachelorsOrHigher;
      });
  
    // draw states
    svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(topojson.feature(counties, counties.objects.states).features)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "state")
      .attr("d", pathGenerator);
};
```

Link to the project on codepen: https://codepen.io/reggr0y/pen/QWVoBOR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your codepen in 2 ways:

Based on the freecodecamp [script](https://choropleth-map.freecodecamp.rocks/script.js) it is implied that this [topojson](https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/choropleth_map/counties.json) is already projected. So you can simply comment out the `projection` call below.

```
const pathGenerator = d3.geoPath() //.projection(projection);
```

Perhaps this was called out in the tutorial/ course you are following, and if not, it is common to pre-project for Albers USA maps because it is a constructed map that does not follow real geography (e.g. Alaska and Hawaii are not really where they are).

There is a simpler pre-projected Albers USA in [this example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/u-s-map) for a reference without the choropleth mechanics. Whilst the `projection` is given for data overlays, note in the rendering code Mike Bostock does not use the `projection` and `path` is simply defined as `d3.geoPath()`.

Perhaps, it is also worth reading through the problems/ answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48412565/my-topojson-wont-display-when-adapting-a-canonical-example) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120033/putting-coordinate-value-on-topojson-us-map) from Andrew Reid.

Second, you draw the states over the top of the counties, so make the fill `none` and the stroke `black`:

```
// draw states
svg.selectAll(".state")
  .data(topojson.feature(counties, counties.objects.states).features)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "state")
  .attr("d", pathGenerator)
  .attr("fill", "none") // <-- add 
  .attr("stroke", "black"); // <-- add
```

Here's the outcome from removing the projection - note you just see the black states because they overlay the counties:

[image]

Here's the outcome from making the adjustments to the state fill and stroke (means that your application of `colorScale` for the fill was correct):

[image]

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply. I have applied the solution you were proposing in the meanwhile (projection and scaleColor issues) and it works. Thanks for your help!